# LogicException with message '... must return a relationship instance.'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tried searching the entire internet for this error, but all in vain, so as a last resort, I'm creating a question here on StackOverflow.

I have two simple Eloquent Models set up:
**1. Teacher** (extends Authenticable) - since I'm using MultiAuth for the system.
**2. GeneralNotice** (extends Eloquent/Model)

`app\Teacher.php`

```
public function generalNotices()
{
    $this->hasMany('App\Modules\GeneralNotice');
}
```

`app\Modules\GeneralNotice.php`

```
public function teacher()
{
    $this->belongsTo('App\Teacher');
}
```

**This is my migration table for General Notices:**

`database/migrations/***_create_general_notices_table.php`

```
Schema::create('general_notices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->longtext('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('attachment')->nullable();
        $table->integer('teacher_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('teacher_id')->references('id')->on('teachers');
        $table->date('dated_on')->default(now());
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I have also seeded the database with a sample notice, to check if it works.

When I try to access any of these relations, I run into an error.

`$teacher = Teacher::find(1);
$teacher->generalNotices;`

***LogicException with message 'App\Teacher::generalNotices must return a relationship instance.'***

`$notice = GeneralNotice::find(1);
$notice->teacher;`

***LogicException with message 'App\Modules\GeneralNotice::teacher must return a relationship instance.'***

If I try to access the member function,
`$teacher->generalNotices()` OR
`$notice->teacher()`

I get **null**.

Please help.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to `return` relationship, for example:

```
public function teacher()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Teacher');
}
```

Comment: @AmruthPillai I just did exactly the same thing as you lol, only by coming across this answer did I suddenly realise!

Comment: Adding a comment as this is the first entry in the search results. 

Unlike with this question, In some cases you don't want to return a relationship, the issue would be how you call the method. It's easy in Laravel to get used to `model->something` but if you are not defining a relationship then call it as a method, eg, `model->something()`

Comment: if you are **NOT CREATING RELATIONSHIP? :)**  - this error is also thrown, when you forget  `()` in the method call, so laravel then thinks you are invoking relationship call, but your method is not about that right :) e.g. `protected function getAllowed(){...}` but then `foreach($this->getAllowed as $some){...}` - note the missing `()`